# ArrayList of objects intuition

Tags: java

I'm trying a coding skillbuilder where the goal is to make a stack that has a max # of elements, and so if too many pushes causes an overflow a new stack is created and push() and pop() operate on this new stack.  If that new stack is completely popped off, then control returns to the previous stack.

I created an ArrayList to hold all my stacks.  I'm new to ArrayLists and have run into issues, but here's my thinking:

- an ArrayList of ints holds a container to store an int at each element, and you have to manually fill an element with something like myArrayList.set(0,13).
- therefore, an ArrayList of Stacks holds a container to store a reference to a stack at each element.

But how do you store a reference to a stack?  I can't just do myArrayList.set(0,Stack myStack).  I think the right answer might be myArrayList.set(0,new Stack()) but that doesn't fit with intuition.  Just like an ArrayList of int's just holds containers, an ArrayList of stack references should not already be holding stack references, just empty containers.

Where is my thinking wrong?

Comment: First problem: you can't have an `ArrayList<int>` due to the fact that generics don't work with primitives in Java...

Comment: Do you have any particular data structure in mind for the stacks themselves?  `LinkedList` might be a good option.  And what is actually going to go inside each stack?

Comment: There are numerous ways to answer this question, but if you're trying to build your skills, I suggest that you try coding this up, along with various alternatives, to get a better feel.  Run it under a debugger to see how it works.  This will help build your skills as well as your intuition -- you won't get that if we tell you the answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet - You could've been nicer and hinted that `ArrayList<Integer>` would be OK.

Comment: I created a stack using a linkedlist.  Part of what is throwing me off is the code looks very odd.  To try to set the "top" instance variable of a particular stack I'm using myArrayList.get(stack#).top = someNode.  Please advise if this is way off, but getting through this...

Comment: Think that an ArrayList always stores references to other objects. So you can have an ArrayList<Integer>, not an ArrayList<int>. I don't know if this idea would help you, but also think that a Stack may be just another reference to one end of the real Stack

Comment: Well, the `LinkedList` class has various methods that prevent you from needing to write `.top =`.  You could use `push` and `pop`, for example.

Comment: @PM77-1: I could, but I was on my way out...

Answer (score 0):

If you're going stick with ArrayList, you could try

```
myArrayList.add(0, new Stack());
```

The add method used with an index (0 in this case) will push the other entries in the ArrayList down (or to be precise, to the right, as per the documentation). When you want to "pop" a stack out of myArrayList, call

```
myArrayList.remove(0);
```

This will remove the Stack at 0, and move the other Stack objects up (or to the left).